# How to select same range for all sheets in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm  using a code below to auto-zoom my sheet for selected ranges. But i have lots of additional sheets so how can i use this code for all sheets instead of writing their name.

Regards.

Code:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Configuration").Activate
Range("A1:AA1").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        wrkSht.Activate
        Range("A1:AA1").Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
        Range("A1").Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop thru all the sheets.

```
for each sht in workbooks(your workbook)
    Your code here
next sht
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the range and sheets and then zoom:

```
Sub Test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AA1").Select
    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select    'removed the selection/grouping
End Sub
```

(This still requires their names, but not individual processing.)

If it is all of the sheets then you can use `Worksheets.Select` as the third statement.